# PHP how to cache POST request?

Tags: php, caching

In my cart I have a 'go back' button. When I'm removing sth from the cart the page is refreshed. And when I click the back button here, the action of removing sth from the cart is reverted. I found the solution not to cache this action of removing something in the cart but it doesn't work (clicking back button shows 'Confirm Form Resubmission' page). I'm using these headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

what could be wrong? I'm using Symfony 2.

Answer (score 0):

> the action of removing sth from the cart is reverted

No its not. The html showing the number of items in the cart *may* be cached (even in the absence of any direction to do so).

There are also problems around what the browser and server should do when the user clicks back to navigate to a page which was the result of a post.

One solution to the latter problem is to do a redirect after handling the post but at the cost of adding some delay.

Your 'go back' button appears to implement a backwards step in the browser using javascript.

There are ways to provide for most behaviours but only a some of these will be within users expectations, some are very complex to achieve, and its far from clear from your post how you want the system to behave.